# Abort GCM message broadcast not working below Android 4

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

Can't find a solution for this behavior:
When receiving a message from GCM the broadcast receiver from the manifest handles it correctly (creating a notification) but I want it to do another thing if the app is on screen (show a toast and cancel the notification).

Here is the code on the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiverPlus"
              android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<!-- Receives the registration id. -->
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<!-- Category -->
<category android:name="org.example.hello" />
</intent-filter>
```

And this is the code that works on JB, but not below:

```
    public BroadcastReceiver registerCustomBR(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE");
    filter.setPriority(1);
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString("text");
            CharSequence text = "Message received in app: " + message;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Message received: "+message);
            ElementWave.messageReceived(context, intent);
            abortBroadcast();
         }
     };

     this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
     return receiver;
}
```

Pretty new to android, so I hope there is a simple solution or anything obvious that I am missing...